# How can I delay the start of WPF application on windows startup?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a WPF application that will run on startup.
I added my application in the registry with the followwing code:

```
        public void RunOnStartup(bool isChecked)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (isChecked)
        {
            registryKey.SetValue("My Program", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location +"\"");
       
        }
        else
        {
            registryKey.DeleteValue("777xUtility");
        }
    }
```

I confirmed that it was registered correctly on the registry. But once I restart my system and log in. My application didnt run. I also have a UI so i think i cannot do it as a service.

Upon checking the event viewer. I got this error:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
 at System.Windows.Window.VerifyNotClosing()
   at System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.String, System.String, Int32)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(IntPtr, System.String, System.String, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.String, System.String)
   at _777x_Utility.BlackScreen.SetBlackWindowPositionToAux()
   at _777x_Utility.BlackScreen.Window_Loaded(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

I had no problem running it manually. This only occurs only during startup.
Now, I wanted to have a delay before opening my application on start up because i think some system files are not loaded yet. I found a solution here but I'm still having the same problem.

Here is the solution i got here but it is not working for me.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //If a command line argument was passed and it was some special string,
        //   then we want to do the sleep.  Otherwise, we don't sleep and just
        //   continue on right away.
        if (e.Args.Length == 1 && e.Args[0] == "startup")
        {
            //Sleep for 60 seconds
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
        }

        //Continue on...
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Are there other ways to delay the opening of my application during start up? Or other ways to launch my application on startup?

[EDIT]
Here is my code for the SetBlackWindowPositiontoAux

```
 public void SetBlackWindowPositionToAux()
    {
        try
        {
            bool isSuccessful;
            int result;

            //remove window style
            result = Libraries.SetWindowLong(blackScreenHandle, Libraries.GWL_STYLE, Libraries.WS_VISIBLE);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error when setting black window to maximized. Result");
            }

            isSuccessful = Libraries.SetWindowPos(blackScreenHandle, Libraries.HWND_TOPMOST, MainWindowValues.Instance.AuxScreen.Bounds.Left, MainWindowValues.Instance.AuxScreen.Bounds.Top, MainWindowValues.Instance.AuxScreen.Bounds.Width, MainWindowValues.Instance.AuxScreen.Bounds.Height, Libraries.SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotSendChangingEvent);
            if (!isSuccessful)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error when setting black window position to auxillary screen. Not Successful");
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, ": SetBlackWindowPositionToAux");
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: > “ Now, I wanted to have a delay before opening my application on start up because i think some system files are not loaded yet” - I can guarantee you that this is NOT the cause of any problems you’re having.

Comment: You are correct about your program being incompatible with running as a Windows Service because it has a GUI (technically, it’s *possible* but there’s no desktop for your program to display its windows in).

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

I am currently checking the VerifyNotClosing. The 2nd condition might have triggered the exception.

        private void VerifyNotClosing()
        {
            if (_isClosing == true)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidOperationDuringClosing));
            }
 
            if (IsSourceWindowNull == false && IsCompositionTargetInvalid == true)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidCompositionTarget));
            }
        }

Comment: here is the link: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,08803a2385930d32

though im still not sure about it

Comment: The error is in your `SetBlackWindowPositionToAux` method. What does this method do? Please post your source code.

Comment: Hi Dai, 
I updated my post and added the code.

It basically uses setwindowpos to move a window to my 2nd screen

Comment: Why are you catching `NullReferenceException`?!?!?!

Comment: This is a debugging problem, specifically lack thereof

Comment: it was only for debugging purposes to make sure the handle of the  window and other parameters are not null

Comment: Maybe a stupid solution, but when the program runs on startup the working directory is `c:\windows\system32` and not the directory where the exe is, could you use that knowledge to realize you are starting on startup, and implement a delay before doing those operations?

Comment: @TheGeneral what is your preferred way to debug a program while it automatically starts with windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a different approach.

I found out that you can also launch an application on startup by creating a shortcut of the executable on the startup folder.

this is what i did on the visual studio installer projects:

1. Right click on the target machine.
2. Add special folder then select User's startup folder
3. On the application folder, create a shortcut for the primary output. you can rename the shortcut if you want.
4. Drag the created shortcut to the User's Startup Folder.
5. Build the installer

After installation, the software will now run on startup.